# Autosaving files with multiple instances

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, autosave

I'm writing a Qt/C++ program that does long-running simulations, and to guard against data loss, I wrote some simple autosave behaviour.  The program periodically saves to the user's temp directory (using QDir::temp()), and if the program closes gracefully, this file is deleted.  If the program starts up and sees the file in that directory, it assumes a previous instance crashed or was forcibly ended, and it prompts the user about loading it.

Now here is the complication - I'd like this functionality to work properly even if multiple instances of the program are used at once.  So when the program loads, it can't just look for the presence of an autosave file.  If it finds one, it needs to determine if that file was created by a running instance (in which case, there's nothing wrong and nothing to be done) or if it has been left over by a instance that crashed or was forcibly ended (in which case it should prompt the user about loading it).

My program is for Windows/Mac/Linux, so what would be the best way to implement this using Qt or otherwise in a cross-platform fashion?

**Edit:**
The comments suggested the use of the process identifier, which I can get using QCoreApplication::applicationPid().  I like this idea, but when the program loads and sees a file with a certain PID in the name, how can it look at the other running instances (if any) to see if there is a match?

Comment: Write filenames integrated with pid, and on load, parse through and ensure each is still running?

Comment: @polarysekt That was my initial idea. However, if the system crashes and has to be shutdown, there is always the (remote) possibility of having clashing pids. I agree that it is most of the way to a solution, however.

Comment: Or compare the last modification time with your update cycle. now - last modification > update cycle, then it is probably from a crashed program. Best would be to combine that with @polarysekt s idea..

Comment: @Yuushi. Good point. I'm commenting instead of answering as I'm only brainstorming. As I suppose a system may crash only partially, the system uptime wouldn't be reliable either... Obviously if the new running pid matched a tempfile, it would indicate a crash, but I'm thinking some kind of DDE with the pid's in question, or some kind of socket, as only your program would respond a certain way to certain inquiries. But that may incur more overhead than necessary... hrm

Comment: @rrwick: have you found any cross-platform solution to your problem? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: @Boris No, I haven't found an ideal solution.  I use the process ID to create autosave files with unique names and then I delete them when the program closes correctly.  What I haven't done is made the program look for orphaned autosaves.  It can show the user to the temp directory, but it's up to the user to find any files they need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [QSaveFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsavefile.html#details) which, as the documentation states:-

> The QSaveFile class provides an interface for safely writing to files.
>
> QSaveFile is an I/O device for writing text and binary files, without losing existing data if the writing operation fails.
>
> While writing, the contents will be written to a temporary file, and if no error happened, commit() will move it to the final file. This ensures that no data at the final file is lost in case an error happens while writing, and no partially-written file is ever present at the final location. Always use QSaveFile when saving entire documents to disk.

As for multiple instances, you just need to reflect that in the filename.

Comment: That looks like a nice class for saving files, and I actually might try using it, but it doesn't look like it specifically addresses the autosave needs I have.

Comment: Note that there is also a QTemporaryFile class: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtemporaryfile.html